# Hungarian accented letters without the physical keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I need to write text in Hungarian on my laptop with an English keyboard. Hungarian has special accented letters.

How can I effectively type these letters?

Comment: You need to add or replace the current standard English (US or UK or...) with the same layout but with the "dead keys" variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the on-screen keyboard **onboard**

```
sudo apt install onboard
```

run the program from dash or a menu or from a terminal window

```
onboard &
```

and set the keyboard to Hungarian with

```
setxkbmap hu
```

and afterwards reset to for example US English with

```
setxkbmap us
```

You will see the Hungarian keys on the onboard keyboard, and you can use it by clicking with the mouse cursor or use your regular keyboard, now that you see which keys have the special Hungarian characters.

[image]

There are more special characters, if you press the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

*English (US, international with dead keys)* is one option. With that layout you get access to e.g. the `dead_acute` and `dead_doubleacute` symbols.

Examples:

<kbd>'</kbd> followed by <kbd>U</kbd> results in ú

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> followed by <kbd>U</kbd> results in ű