# Typing several foreign characters with a single keyboard layout in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, gui, language-support

Since I am a hobbyist polyglot and **I need to write in a few languages which have extra letters**, I would like to find a good way to either customise my current keyboard layout or use a new one.

For instance, I need the letters ß,ä,ö,ü in German; å,ä,ö,æ,ø in Swedish; ç,é,è,à, and some dead keys such as acute, grave, dieresis in French and Spanish, and so on. My main language is French and I am used to the QWERTZ layout with the special chars being like in the Swiss variant. Since every country seems to choose differently where the special chars are, I don't want to simply enable the country's official layout. **Alternatively, I would be ready to switch to another layout** such as a special Dvorak or Colemak disposition, but I just can't find one which fits my needs and include all the letters I want, even as dead keys or with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Maj</kbd>...

**What I currently do** is modifying directly the `ch` file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`, and then adding an entry in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`, then running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`, then (extra step in Wayland) adding the entry in dconf under `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.sources`, and finally I restart my session, and it works. I was advised to do so, but from times to times, the files I modify get replaced by updates and I have to do it again (pretty annoying). And moreover, I don't understand completely how it works : I tried once to create a fully new layout in a new file, but I was then unable to activate it from the GNOME Settings....

My problem is that I have to switch constantly between keyboard layouts (which isn't actually a true problem since I only use one language at a time), and **my current way of customising them is pretty long and annoying**. If it were easier than modifying the above mentioned files, I could go further and find better solutions.

What do you think about it ? Is there a GUI to do it ? Or does a layout for Ubuntu exist which provides support for many European languages ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Defining and using a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose) is one way.

Answer (score 0):

### Virtual keyboard

It helps to find the special characters (and identify the layout in general), if you use a virtual keyboard, for example `onboard`.

See this link,

[Hungarian accented letters without the physical keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873724/hungarian-accented-letters-without-the-physical-keyboard/873735?s=2|16.4786#873735)

This makes it easier, when you switch keyboard layout between languages.

### Suggested method

I think you might prefer to use **US English keyboard with international symbols**, which is described at the following link,

[Making Umlauts in ubuntu 17.10 on a ThinkPad430](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967708/making-umlauts-in-ubuntu-17-10-on-a-thinkpad430/968758#968758)